# Get the vendor of an executable file on UNIX-LIKE systems

Tags: file, unix, executable, vendor

I am trying to **collect the vendor of an executable file under differents UNIX-LIKE systems**  ( Red Hat, AIX, Solaris, Oracle Linux ...).
I would like to do the same as the following command on Windows :

```
WMIC  /LOCALE:MS_409 DATAFILE WHERE (Name="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-10\\bin\\java.exe") GET manufacturer
```

I have looked at the **file and strings command without success**.
No clue how to achieve it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no standard to embed any vendor information in a executable file. Some vendor information might be available from the (system specific) package management system.

Comment: Files don't have vendors. You are trying something impossible that smells like an X-Y-problem.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out UNIX files do not have a vendor, mostly because there is no standard for it, but RPM-based distributions like Red Hat provide a "vendor" that can be queried with a command like this:

```sh
rpm -qa --queryformat '%{NAME}TAB%{DISTRIBUTION}TAB%{VENDOR}\n'
```

(Use a TAB character for `TAB` in the code above if you want to load it into a spreadsheet program or similar)

`rpmkeys --querytags` lists all known query tags like `NAME`.

Comment: Sadly, as I have pointed out, I need a standard solution for different platforms. I'm looking for a workaround to be able to get vendors of java installations. Actually, it concerns only this type of software. Previously, I was thinking there was existing an OS command to do the job in the UNIX environment.

Comment: You can only query what is there: So there does not exist such a standard command to query as the information you want to know is not present in general. Maybe explain *why* you need this information at all.